# SQL Server bulk insert left join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to bulk insert into a new table from the uploaded file but I also want to insert a data from other table using left join, can you check what is wrong with my query?

```
    INSERT INTO gen048_ACCNUMS (accnum)
    SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',10), CHAR(9), '')
    FROM #temp1

set @sql = '
    INSERT INTO '+@sourceTable+' (ftype, ccode, refdate, dupload, accname, add1, add2, zip, add3, add4, add5, accdate, book, solcode)
    SELECT

        ''GEN048'',
        '''',
        ('+@refd+'),
        (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),GETDATE(), 101)),
        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',0),
        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',1),
        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',2),
        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',3), 
        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',4),
        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',5),
        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',6), 
        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',7),

        (select substring(dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',8), 1, 1)),
        (select substring(dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,''|'',8), 1, 3)),

        (SELECT branch
            FROM '+@sourceTable+'
            LEFT JOIN BRANCH_LIST ON '+@sourceTable+'.solcode = BRANCH_LIST.solcode)

    FROM #temp1'

        print @sql
        exec (@sql)

    SELECT 'File has been successfully uploaded', @fileDate,'success' as msg

END
```

This is the SQL message

> FROM #temp1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Does it produce an error?  Is it doing the wrong thing?

Comment: can you also post the output of `print @sql` ?

Comment: Without telling us the exact issue/error message, it's hard for us to help you.

Comment: `FROM #temp1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're missing a comma before this subquery:

(SELECT branch
            FROM '+@sourceTable+'
            LEFT JOIN BRANCH_LIST ON '+@sourceTable+'.solcode = BRANCH_LIST.solcode)

Regardless though, the error you're receiving is because that subquery is returning more than one row and it's in the select portion of your query. You'll need to figure out how to get just one row (e.g.: TOP (1) )...or back to the drawing board on how to accomplish your task.

I would also add that if that subquery does not depend on any values from your "main" query, you may want to use a cross-join to the subquery in the from clause.